# MPMediaItemCollection Count - NSUInteger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsuinteger

I'm trying to use the `MPMediaItemCollection` count property to sort the items in an array. When I try to sort an array with this `NSUInteger` property, and it doesn't work. When I try to print it (`NSLog(@"%lx",count);`) it doesn't print correctly.

How do I get the `NSUInteger` to work correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this will help.  This works for me using MPMediaCollection:

```
[everything setGroupingType: MPMediaGroupingGenre];
NSArray *genreLists = [everything collections];

for (MPMediaItemCollection *genreList in genreLists) {
    NSLog (@"count: %d", [genreList count]);
}
```

Comment: This works. I figured out that there is a bug when the grouping type is set to album instead of genre.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this statement: I use it and it prints out just find for me

`NSLog(@"%d",count);`